# Python : extract .csv results after submitting data to a form with mechanize

Tags: php, python, forms, csv

I'm new to extracting data from the web with Python. Thanks to some other posts and this [webpage](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/), I figured out how to submit data to a form, using the module `mechanize`.

Now, I am stuck with finding how to extract the results. There are lots of different results when submitting the form, but if I could get access to the csv files that would be perfect. I assume you have to use the module `re`, but then how do you download the results via Python ?

After running the job, the csv files are here: Summary => Results => Download Heavy Chain Table (you can just click "load example" to see how the webpage works).

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this

url = 'http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/index.php'
response = br.open(url)

br.form = list(br.forms())[1]

# Controls can be found by name
control1 = br.form.find_control("light")

# Text controls can be set as a string
br["light"] = "DIQMTQSPASLSASVGETVTITCRASGNIHNYLAWYQQKQGKSPQLLVYYTTTLADGVPSRFSGSGSGTQYSLKINSLQPEDFGSYYCQHFWSTPRTFGGGTKLEIKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC" 
br["heavy"] = "QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFSLTGYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLHTDDTARYYCARERDYRLDYWGQGTTLTVSSASTTPPSVFPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSPRPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRDC"

# To submit form
response = br.submit()
content = response.read()
# print content

result = re.findall(r"Prob_Heavy.csv", content)
print result
```

When printing `content`, the lines that I'm interested looks like :

```
<h2>Results</h2><br>
Predictions for Heavy Chain:
<a href='u17003I9f1/Prob_Heavy.csv'>Download Heavy Chain Table</a><br>
Predictions for Light Chain:
<a href='u17003I9f1/Prob_Light.csv'>Download Light Chain Table</a><br>
```

So the question is : how do I download / get access to `href='u17003I9f1/Prob_Heavy.csv'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty example using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` to avoid parsing HTML using regular expressions. `sudo pip install bs4` if you have `pip` but not `BeautifulSoup` installed already.

```
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this

url_base = "http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/"
url_index = url_base + "index.php"

response = br.open(url_index)

br.form = list(br.forms())[1]

# Controls can be found by name
control1 = br.form.find_control("light")

# Text controls can be set as a string
br["light"] = "DIQMTQSPASLSASVGETVTITCRASGNIHNYLAWYQQKQGKSPQLLVYYTTTLADGVPSRFSGSGSGTQYSLKINSLQPEDFGSYYCQHFWSTPRTFGGGTKLEIKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASVVCFLNNFYPKDINVKWKIDGSERQNGVLNSWTDQDSKDSTYSMSSTLTLTKDEYERHNSYTCEATHKTSTSPIVKSFNRNEC" 
br["heavy"] = "QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFSLTGYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLHTDDTARYYCARERDYRLDYWGQGTTLTVSSASTTPPSVFPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSPRPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRDC"

# To submit form
response = br.submit()
content = response.read()
# print content

soup = bs(content)
urls_csv = [x.get("href") for x in soup.findAll("a") if ".csv" in x.get("href")]
for file_path in urls_csv:
    status_code = 404
    retries = 0
    url_csv = url_base + file_path
    file_name = url_csv.split("/")[-1]
    while status_code == 404 and retries < 10:
        print "{} not ready yet".format(file_name)
        req = requests.get(url_csv )
        status_code = req.status_code
        time.sleep(5)
    print "{} ready. Saving.".format(file_name)
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(req.content)
```

Running the script in the REPL:

```
Prob_Heavy.csv not ready yet
Prob_Heavy.csv not ready yet
Prob_Heavy.csv not ready yet
Prob_Heavy.csv ready. Saving.
Prob_Light.csv not ready yet
Prob_Light.csv ready. Saving.
>>> 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's a hack to parse HTML with regex, if the format is always the same that could work:

```
result=re.findall("<a href='([^']*)'>",contents)
```

Not sure either if it's the best/fashionable solution but then I'd use `wget` to download the files

```
import wget
for r in result:
    # compute full url
    csv_file = url.rpartition("/")[0]+"/"+r
    print("downloading {}".format(csv_file))
    # downloads and saves the .csv file in the current directory
    # "flattening" the path replacing slashes by underscores
    wget.download(csv_file,out=r.replace("/","_"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks not so far from the answer, but the matter is the files obtained are empty. How could we fix this ? It seems that the results are not stored on the web.

Comment: that's a pity. I'm sure that wget would crash if the file was not found. So maybe that they're empty, or maybe you could try to mix my answer with Christopher answer (using `urllib` in python 3) to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do, mixing your two answers, it seems like a good option.

Comment: please tell me / suggest edit if you make it work with Christopher answer, so my answer works.

Comment: you mean you get  zero-len files? what about trying to paste URL in firefox directly?

Comment: Pasting to firefox directly works fine, I get the file that I want. But what is strange is that when I use `href = 'u17003XjgB/Prob_Heavy'` is does work, but not  when I want to access the result this way : `href2 = result[0]`

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, which it looks like you're using, use `urllib2`.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> URL = "http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/u17003I9f1/Prob_Heavy.csv"
>>> urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
```

Or if you're trying to it dynamically based on the `href`, you can do:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> href='u17003I9f1/Prob_Heavy.csv'
>>> URL = 'http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/' + href
>>> urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the precedent answers work fine... if the webpage exists. However, when the job is running, the program takes its times (roughly 30 seconds). So I found the answer by putting the program on pause with the `time` module :

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import time

print "Job running..."
time.sleep(60)

csv_files = []

for href in result:
    URL = "http://circe.med.uniroma1.it/proABC/" + href + ".csv"    
    csv_files.append(urlopen(URL).read())
    print("downloading {}".format(URL))

print "Job finished"
print csv_files
```

I'm not sure this is the more elegant solution, but I does work in this case.